# How do I format a document to have more than three columns?

Tags: google-docs

Google Docs currently only allows formatting documents with one, two, or three columns. AppScript does not appear to be able to set the column format. How can I format a document with four or more columns?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the HTML of the page can allow you to set more than three columns. Open the column options dialogue by selecting Format > Columns > More options. Locate the "Number of columns" dropdown's HTML element in the code inspector. There will be three similar elements. The currently-selected dropdown element's "tabindex" field will be set to 0. The other two will be set to -1. Modify the "data-value" field of the currently-selected dropdown element to 4.

[image: Screenshot of Google Docs, editing HTML]

Hit apply. Your text will be formatted with four columns.

[image: Result of creating four columns]